# Open popup.html anchor in new tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, facebook-sharer

My problem atm is with manifest v2.

Since I've been developing this extension I've been facing a lot of problems because the new manifest V2 of google extensions, that removed the capacity of inline javascript in the html files.

So can someone tell me how to open a link in a new tab with the new manifest?

My html:

```
<li ng-repeat="pageInfo in pageInfos">
    <img src="{{pageInfo.url}}" class="link"/>
    <img src="http://www.end-timeillusion.com/images/site/sn_icons/facebook.fw.png" class="fbshare"/>
</li>
```

My external.js - don't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fbshare').click(function(){
        chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + $(.link).attr('src')});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code:

```
$(.link).attr('src')
```

You need quotation marks around .link, like this:

```
$('.link').attr('src')
```

I tested your code in a test extension and the link opened in a new window, once I added the quotation marks.

Comment: Still not working for me, the facebook icon dont links to anithing, it's like a simple image, what's wrong with my extension, if it works on you

Comment: Are you not getting a new tab when clicking or are you not getting an icon? What's the exact problem now?

Comment: in my popup I have the image or the website and an icon of the facebook on the right of the images, and when I click both images it does nothing, the facebook icon, suposably, should open a new tab with facebook sharer

Comment: the facebook icon opens a new windwo for me. Not sure why it's not working for you.